# @UniqueConstraint and @Column(unique = true) in hibernate annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

What is difference between **@UniqueConstraint** and **@Column(unique = true)**?

For example:

```
@Table(
   name = "product_serial_group_mask", 
   uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"mask", "group"})}
)
```

And

```
@Column(unique = true)
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private ProductSerialMask mask;

@Column(unique = true)
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Group group;
```

Comment: Note: With Hibernate 5.4, when I added `unique=true`, the index was not added by the scheme auto-updater. `@UniqueConstraint` made it appear. Could be a bug.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

As said before, `@Column(unique = true)` is a shortcut to `UniqueConstraint` when it is only a single field.

From the example you gave, there is a huge difference between both.

```
@Column(unique = true)
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private ProductSerialMask mask;

@Column(unique = true)
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Group group;
```

This code implies that both `mask` and `group` have to be unique, but separately. That means that if, for example, you have a record with a **mask.id = 1** and tries to insert another record with **mask.id = 1**, you'll get an error, because that column should have unique values. The same aplies for group.

On the other hand,

```
@Table(
   name = "product_serial_group_mask", 
   uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"mask", "group"})}
)
```

Implies that the values of mask + group combined should be unique. That means you can have, for example, a record with **mask.id = 1** and **group.id = 1**, and if you try to insert another record with **mask.id = 1** and **group.id = 2**, it'll be inserted successfully, whereas in the first case it wouldn't.

If you'd like to have both mask and group to be unique separately and to that at class level, you'd have to write the code as following:

```
@Table(
        name = "product_serial_group_mask",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "mask"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "group")
        }
)
```

This has the same effect as the first code block.

Comment: Once the unique constraint is created am I able to reference the constraint by name in my JPA Repository to query on that?

Comment: @jDub9 You cannot query an index. You can query the mask and group columns, in one query, and it will use that index for faster processing (if you are lucky), but you cannot simply query an index.

Comment: Beware though that columnNames must be actual names in the database. It should be `mask_id` and `group_id` if you use default naming strategy.

Answer (score 28):

From the Java EE documentation:

> ```
> public abstract boolean unique
> ```
>
> (Optional) Whether the property is a unique key. This is a shortcut for the 
>   UniqueConstraint annotation at the table level and is useful for when the unique key 
>   constraint is only a single field. This constraint applies in addition to any constraint 
>   entailed by primary key mapping and to constraints specified at the table level.

See [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#unique%28%29)

Comment: so when I use this code:
@Column(unique = true)
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private ProductSerialMask mask;

@Column(unique = true)
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Group group;

I have two index but when use other way I have one index that it is combine of two column?

Answer (score 26):

In addition to Boaz's answer ....

`@UniqueConstraint` allows you to **name the constraint**, while `@Column(unique = true)` generates a random name (e.g. `UK_3u5h7y36qqa13y3mauc5xxayq`).

Sometimes it can be helpful to know what table a constraint is associated with. E.g.:

```
@Table(
   name = "product_serial_group_mask", 
   uniqueConstraints = {
      @UniqueConstraint(
          columnNames = {"mask", "group"},
          name="uk_product_serial_group_mask"
      )
   }
)
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to @Boaz's and @vegemite4me's answers....

By implementing `ImplicitNamingStrategy` you may create rules for automatically naming the constraints. Note you add your naming strategy to the `metadataBuilder` during Hibernate's initialization:

```
metadataBuilder.applyImplicitNamingStrategy(new MyImplicitNamingStrategy());
```

It works for `@UniqueConstraint`, but not for `@Column(unique = true)`, which always generates a random name (e.g. UK_3u5h7y36qqa13y3mauc5xxayq).

There is a bug report to solve this issue, so **if you can, please vote there to have this implemented.** Here:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11586

Thanks.